# CORS using Express and NextJS not allow origin when production

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, next.js

I'm using Express and want to setup my cors settings dynamically.
My express app is hosted on local host 3001, and my nextjs is on localhost 3000.

```
// If production env, access CORS for Vercel app. 
const allowedOrigin = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://dev-markdown-client.vercel.app' : 'http://localhost:3000';
app.use(cors({
    origin: allowedOrigin,
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus:  200
}));
```

On client side I setup similar using axios and creted a base url:I want to call the node local server 3001 when being on development. and the vercel link whe being on production. But is not working..

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const Backend_URL_API = axios.create({
    baseURL: env === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:3001' : 'https://dev-markdown.onrender.com',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

On my signup page I executed the signup function to the backend :

```
export const SignupHttp = async (data: ISignupRequest) => {
    try {
        // Destructuring the data object
        const { email, firstName, lastName, password } : ISignupRequest = data;
        let response = await Backend_URL_API.post('/api/v1/user' , { email, firstName, lastName, password });
        return response.data;
    } 
    catch (error) {
        throw error;  
    }
}
```

But no matter how I try, even if i set the link manually, on production I get:

```
/signup:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-markdown.onrender.com/api/v1/user' from origin 'https://dev-markdown-client.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
80-c860fc26d1398f35.js:6 
        
        
       POST https://dev-markdown.onrender.com/api/v1/user net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, The CORS policy on express  API is allowing requests from `http://localhost:3000` and not `'https://dev-markdown-client.vercel.app'`, where your frontend application is hosted causing the request to be blocked.

the error must be with this statement  :

```
const allowedOrigin = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://dev-markdown-client.vercel.app' : 'http://localhost:3000';
```

maybe you misspelled  **'production'** I guess this `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' is rendering false`  double check it